# Open jQuery dialog with a parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC view from which I want to popup a jQuery dialog. In the dialog, I want to render a view, but the controller action requires a parameter. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .dialog({
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Agenda", new {id = ???})"); //Line to fix
            },
            autoOpen: false
        });
```

And further down, I have this code calling the dialog. Note that the `id` I want to pass to the controller action is `calEvent.id`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }
});
```

So the question is: How can I adapt my code to pass `calEvent` to the `id` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery provides a method which store data for you, no need to use a dummy attribute or to find workaround to your problem.

use the .data() method on the jquery dialog object to bind any data you want to your dialog when calling it, and the same method within the open() function to read it out:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $dialog.data('id', calEvent.id).dialog('open');
}
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            url = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Agenda", new {id = "XXX"})";
            url.replace( "XXX", $(this).data('id') );
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        autoOpen: false
    });
```

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that you render the Url server-side. You would have to replace a part in the pre-rendered URL. I edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. If the parameter you want to pass to your controller is a javascript variable you could use the following:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Agenda")';
    $(this).load(url, { id: someJavascriptVariable });
}
```

Take a look at the documentation of the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. The second argument allows you to pass additional parameters for the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,
It should work as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Agenda", new {id = '<%= calEvent.id %>'})"); //Line to fix
        },
        autoOpen: false
    });
```